# I am marking my object of class C as a “@Autowired(required = false)“, still spring is trying to find its instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am marking my object of class C  as a “@Autowired(required = false)“, still spring is trying to find its instance, I am receiving below error

***Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type class C***

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Foo {

    private A aa;
    private B bb;
    private C cc;

    public Foo(@Autowired final A aa,
               @Autowired final B bb,
               @Autowired(required = false) final C cc) {
        this.aa = aa;
        this.bb = bb;
        this.cc = cc;
    }
```

Comment: try removing the final keyword?

Comment: From the [documentation of `@Autowired`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html): "*Although `@Autowired` can technically be declared on individual method or constructor parameters since Spring Framework 5.0, most parts of the framework ignore such declarations. ... In the case of a multi-arg constructor or method, the `required()` attribute is applicable to all arguments.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation of `@Autowired`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html):

> ...
>
> Autowired Parameters
>
> Although `@Autowired` can technically be declared on individual method or constructor parameters since Spring Framework 5.0, most parts of the framework ignore such declarations. The only part of the core Spring Framework that actively supports autowired parameters is the JUnit Jupiter support in the spring-test module (see the [TestContext framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-junit-jupiter-di) reference documentation for details).
>
> Multiple Arguments and 'required' Semantics
>
> In the case of a multi-arg constructor or method, the [`required()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html#required--) attribute is applicable to all arguments. Individual parameters may be declared as Java-8 style [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html?is-external=true) or, as of Spring Framework 5.0, also as @Nullable or a not-null parameter type in Kotlin, overriding the base 'required' semantics.
>
> ...

So in short this means we should annotate the constructor with `@Autowired` and annotate the optional parameters with `@Nullable` or make them [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html?is-external=true)s.